# Retrieve files tree from a remote repository

Tags: c#, .net, libgit2sharp

I am facing a use case where I would like to connect to a remote repository without cloning it locally or even initing it. Is there any way to implement this using the library? I would like to be able to get all information regarding commits, trees, authors, etc but the only way I have achieved is cloning the repository locally.

As I said I would like to know if this could be achieved using the library.

Thanks in advance!

Get all information from remote repository without cloning the repository locally.